# Append an url parameters every time page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to append a parameters to prevent hard caching every time page reload. This in Js or jQuery.
The url page is always the same, but there's some submit button to proceed in the checkout(address -> shipping-> payment).

I want to know if there's a script that can be use in this way:

```
window.onload {
var thisurl = window.location;
var characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
var result = ""
var charactersLength = characters.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < 15 ; i++ ) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
}

 window.location.replace(thisurl + "?prevent="+ result);
}
```

I want that every time user click on .continue button on checkout and the page will be load and process go ahead but remain same page that i want that change parameters.

How can I do it?

Thanks from Enrico.

Comment: Doing this on page load won't prevent caching (since it's already loaded), you'd need to apply that parameter to the link the user clicks on the previous page for it to be there in time.

Comment: Yes but in this way i remove the problem that customer can't go ahead from cart to checkout page. After apply that we never experience again this problem(it force to recompile page because url is different). But in this case in more difficoult because i need to do on form submit button that have no url... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery this should work.

```js
$('.continue').click(function() {
    var thisurl = window.location;
    var random = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
    window.location.replace(thisurl + "?prevent="+ random);
    alert(thisurl + "?prevent="+ random);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="continue">continue</button>
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get also the destination url when you click on continue and not the actual page?

Comment: Yes, what should be the destination? Here an example: `window.location.replace("https://example.com/checkout.php?prevent="+ random);`

Comment: Hi, what i mean is if is it possible to get the url of submit action, without alterate. Because if i specify an url the submit not work as expected. Regards from Enrico.

Comment: Yes, what's the URL?

Comment: Hi, this is website.[link](https://campoelettrico.it/) if you add something to cart, then go ahead and enter on checkout page you see orange button, with continue. If i insert the script i'm not able to save or continue because take a wrong url. If you can check let me know. many many thanks!

Comment: Is this the URL of the submit action? https://campoelettrico.it/ordine